# Is there a way to force windows to cache a file?

Tags: windows, caching

Is there like batch command or something that will force windows to cache that file? I am trying to create a game preloader that loads certain game files into cache before starting the game. Is there any way I can do this?

updated int main code:

```
int main(int argc, const char** argv)
{
if(argc >= 2) for(int i = 1; argv[i]; ++i) pf("C:\\Games\World_of_Tanks\res\packages\gui.pkg"[i]);
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

All you need to do is load the files, either using `ReadFile` or by memory mapping the files and touching every page (in fact, due to allocation granularity every 16th page suffices, but in theory you should be touching every page).
Memory mapping is faster and more cache-friendly, since you do not need to allocate extra memory to hold the data (which you aren't going to use for anything useful!). The OS will reuse the same physical memory for the cache and for the virtual memory that your process can see.

Several mainstream applications, including Microsoft Office and Adobe Reader do exactly that to launch faster. It's those "delayed start" services that keep your harddisk light flashing for a dozen seconds after you log in.

Do note, however, that while you can force Windows<sup>1</sup> to cache files that way, but you *cannot* force it to *keep* the files in the cache indefinitively. If there is not enough physical RAM available, the system will throw away cache contents in order to satisfy application demands.

EDIT: Minimum working example implementation using filemapping:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <cstdio>

void pf(const char* name)
{
    HANDLE file = CreateFile(name, GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE, 0, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, 0);
    if(file == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) { printf("couldn't open %s\n", name); return; };

    unsigned int len  = GetFileSize(file, 0);

    HANDLE mapping  = CreateFileMapping(file, 0, PAGE_READONLY, 0, 0, 0);
    if(mapping == 0) { printf("couldn't map %s\n", name); return; }

    const char* data = (const char*) MapViewOfFile(mapping, FILE_MAP_READ, 0, 0, 0);

    if(data)
    {
        printf("prefetching %s... ", name);

        // need volatile or need to use result - compiler will otherwise optimize out whole loop
        volatile unsigned int touch = 0;

        for(unsigned int i = 0; i < len; i += 4096)
            touch += data[i];
    }
    else
        printf("couldn't create view of %s\n", name);

    UnmapViewOfFile(data);
    CloseHandle(mapping);
    CloseHandle(file);
}

int main(int argc, const char** argv)
{
    if(argc >= 2) for(int i = 1; argv[i]; ++i) pf(argv[i]);
    return 0;
}
```

The program will try to prefetch any filename given on the commandline.
The code isn't overly pretty but it works. It uses ANSI filenames, and leaks a file handle in case opening succeeds but mapping fails (but bleh... it's not *really* a problem, the OS will clean up after the program exits -- if that annoys you, wrap the handles in RAII). It's also limited to ca. 1.8GiB file size due to address space in a 32-bit build, otherwise limited to 4GiB due to `GetFileSize`, but that's also trivial to fix if you really need that big a file.
Instead of `volatile` one might want to return or otherwise consume the "result", but either way works (`volatile` does not truly have a measurable impact on performance, compared to a disk access!).

---

<sup>1</sup>Truth being told, you actually can't force Windows, but it incidentially always works that way unless you explicitly request unbuffered I/O.
In theory, you *could* force the OS to read pages into memory and even force it to keep them in RAM by locking the memory, but your working set quota (wich is very small, and you need aministrative rights to modify it) will not normally let you do this. That's a good thing though, since locking large amounts of memory is a very bad idea.

Comment: Great I will look into using this for my preloader. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, although this one looks more like C than C++, really. I think including <cstdio> instead of <stdio.h> (I hate iostream, so still using stdio to print!) is the only thing in that code that prevents it from passing as plain normal C :-)

Comment: Hey if you are still looking at this, which pf() do I add the file path (happens to be C:\\Games\World_of_Tanks\res\packages\gui.pkg, this is the file I want to load into the memory or "prefetch")

Comment: Obviously, yes. Otherwise the OS will not be able to find it. You will need to put it in quotes if there's a space after "World", too.

Comment: It's an underscore, don't know why I forgot to include that...anyway which one of the pf() do I put the file path in? (there is one on void pf() and one in main pf()) thanks for your reply.

Comment: If you want to hardcode the filename, you would put it in the function call which is inside main. But if you just compile that program as-is (let's say as `pf.exe`) you can invoke it as `pf.exe file_to_load` from within `cmd` or in a link's target. It works for several file names, too. That way you are more flexible.

Comment: I want to hardcode the filename (as I am only going to cache a single ~577mb file) I added the file name in quotes with the proper C:\\ syntax and it gave me a few errors, including invalid conversion from char to const char and error initialzing arguement 1 of 'void pf(const char)'. My knowledge of c++ is limited to about 3 hours of online guides, so sorry if I am sounding a little stupid

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for and helped me a great deal! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I understand this Q/A is pretty old, but I came across this and found it to be inadequate for my own purposes. Here's a more straightforward way to do this that I came up with in "modern" Windows PowerShell.

The mechanics of it are the same. You simply need to read the file off the disk, which loads it into memory. Obviously as previously noted, you cannot really force the OS to *keep* the files in memory, but if your RAM quantity is sufficient and your use-case usage is low, then you can assume that there is no reason for the memory to be evicted.

Enough talk, here's the one liner in Windows PowerShell

```
Measure-Command { Get-Childitem -path <your dir> -recurse | Get-FileHash -Algorithm MD5 | Out-Default }
```

You'll note that this does do a little extra CPU work, but if you are trying to cache this off a spinning disk, that will be the bottleneck, not the mere MD5 being run.

So what does this do? Well I added `Measure-Command` because why not? It just dumps the total runtime of the provided command. Not necessary, but gives you an easy answer to "how long did it take?". Just icing on the cake which reads thus

```
Days              : 0
Hours             : 0
Minutes           : 3
Seconds           : 54
Milliseconds      : 659
Ticks             : 2346597665
TotalDays         : 0.00271596951967593
TotalHours        : 0.0651832684722222
TotalMinutes      : 3.91099610833333
TotalSeconds      : 234.6597665
TotalMilliseconds : 234659.7665
```

The rest is pretty straightforward. `Get-Childitem` given your `-path` and told to `-recurse` will operate on everything in the given directory. I've chosen `-Algorithm MD5` for `Get-FileHash` because it's a bit quicker than the other `SHA` hashes. We don't really need anything more than to force read the files and do some operation on ALL the data contained on the disk.

The result is that the entire set of files is read from the disk and hashed, which requires them to be loaded into memory. The operating system will evict them if you do not have enough excess memory on hand. Given a situation where either the files in question are a smaller sum total, or your RAM is sufficiently in excess as to not be evicted, this will effectively precache the files.

Just to followup with my own use-case. I run a really lean machine with about 6-8gb in-use memory at peak usage. The files I wanted to cache run about 17gb on disk. With 32gb total memory, I could count on there being 2-4gb free memory. Free as in, actually unused memory that could either become operating memory, or just contain more cached disk reads. Thus I could count on the files I loaded remaining cached as the system would have no reason to evict them from memory. Over time, they would eventually, but I could simply run my command again to recache whatever may have been evicted. That total ~4 minute runtime I showed above was 100% read from disk fresh after reboot. It is just under one minute runtime with it being run 100% already cached in memory with no disk reads.

P.S. I actually tried piping to `/dev/null` (windows equivalent) and it took over 6 times as long than to simply MD5 hash everything. Can't fathom why, but I was hoping to speed up the process by NOT doing computations on the file contents. Definitely failed by that path.

Leave me a comment if you can think of anything lighter and faster than MD5 hashing for loading file contents into memory!